# Does Mendix generates a source code in any particular language, which can be edited and reused?

Tags: development-environment, mendix

Does Mendix generates a source code in any particular language, which can be edited and reused?
I have never used Mendix

Answer (score 0):

Mendix does not generate source code, apart from the boilerplate source code for custom Java actions. The model you create is interpreted at runtime.

Full disclosure: I am a Mendix employee but what I post here is personal, not an official statement.